# Proof for cyclic permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra

let $\alpha\in S_n$ be an r-cycle for some $2\leq r \leq n.$

Can someone please prove that $\alpha^r=1$

I used $\alpha^r=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,....\alpha_r)=1$ as a starting idea.

Comment: Write $a=(a_1,a_2,\dotsc,a_r)$, let $x$ be an element of $\{1,\dotsc,n\}$, and see what happens when you apply $a$ to $x$ $r$ times.

Answer (score 2):

How it's proved depends on how an $r$-cycle is defined.  I'll use this definition:

> A permutation $\alpha \in S_n$ is called a cycle if there is some $x$ such that $\alpha(i)=i$ for all $i \not\in S$, where $S:=\{x,\alpha(x),\alpha^2(x),\ldots\}$.
>
> The set $S$ is called the support of $\alpha$.
>
> A cycle $\alpha$ is called an $m$-cycle if its support has cardinality $m$.

(*Note*: with this definition, it's not immediate that a $m$-cycle can be written in cycle notation as $(x\ \alpha(x)\ \cdots\ \alpha^{m-1}(x))$.)

> Theorem: An $r$-cycle $\alpha$ with $r \geq 2$ satisfies $\alpha^r=\mathrm{id}$.

*Proof*:  If $\alpha^i(x)=\alpha^j(x)$ for some $0 \leq i < j \leq r-1$, then $x=\alpha^{j-i}(x)$, and so $S=\{x,\alpha(x),\ldots,\alpha^{j-i-1}(x)\}$, contradicting that $|S|=r$.  Hence $\{x,\alpha(x),\ldots,\alpha^{r-1}(x)\}$ is an $r$-element subset of $S$, but since $|S|=r$, we have $$S=\{x,\alpha(x),\ldots,\alpha^{r-1}(x)\}.$$

If we have $\alpha^r \neq \mathrm{id}$, then $\alpha^r(\alpha^i(x)) \neq \alpha^i(x)$ for some $0 \leq i \leq r-1$.  This implies $\alpha^r(x)\neq x$ or equivalently that $\alpha^r(x)=\alpha^j(x)$ for some $j \in \{1,2,\ldots,r-1\}$.

Thus, since $r \geq 2$, we know $$\alpha^{r-1}(x) \mapsto_{\alpha} \alpha^j(x).$$  By definition, we also know $$\alpha^{j-1}(x) \mapsto_{\alpha} \alpha^j(x).$$  But since $j \neq r$, this contradicts the assumption that $\alpha$ is a permutation.